# write function for file handling in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use write function of perl for formatting the output written in a file.but I am not able to do so as it gives me error :use of comma-less variable list is deprecated in line 3.

```
format STDOUT=
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  $text            $text1
.
$text="hello";
$text1="world!";
write;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace it with

```
format STDOUT=
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  ($text, $text1)
.
$text="hello";
$text1="world!";
write;
```

Comment: thanks ,I did what u suggested now the error is gone but its still not displaying the text.

Comment: It won't if you are trying to do it in a perl online interpreter. Try saving it in a file (say hello.pl) and run perl hello.pl. It worked for me.

Comment: I have saved this in a .pl file and trying to run it perl file.pl. but its not showing anything on terminal

Comment: This is strange. It outputs `hello             world!` on my terminal. Does it work for something simple like `print "Hey, world!\n";` (also saved in a file)? Also make sure nothing is misspelled (especially `STDOUT`).

Comment: yes it works for simple print scipts,but I cant figure out why its not giving me a formatted output on terminal for this script

Comment: thanks it worked .the problem was print <> at the start of the script